# How can I prevent a scroll bar from blocking content?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a custom autocomplete drop down list for text inputs. I consists of a `<ul>` element with absolute positioning. It's minimum width should be equal to the width of the input, but it should expand wider if necessary to show all of the content. It should also have a maximum height.

The issue I am running into is that I am getting a horizontal scroll bar (which I don't want) and if I set `overflow-x` to hidden I have the vertical scroll bar covering up part of the content.

I tried adding padding to the right of the `<li>` elements, and this "works", except that there is ugly padding even when no vertical scroll bar is present.

Is there a solution to this?

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vkxdthme/1/)

Comment: where is the textbox?

Comment: @AliMehdi It's not there. Why do you ask? My question has nothing to do with the input element.

Comment: Well... I guess the padding solution is the best in your case :)

Comment: Unless anyone can think of a simple CSS solution I think I'll have to resort to JavaScript to dynamically change the overflow-y style property of the list based on the number of elements.

Comment: If you go with a js solution it would be better if you compare the scroll height against the height and add the scrollbar if the former is bigger. something like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkxdthme/6/). I started to work on it but i saw theres a problem when using padding in general and its already 6 am here so i gave up and didnt post it